# What is the range of multiplied values?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

For real numbers $a \in [\frac{1}{2}, 1)$ and $r = 2 - a$, what is the range of $a \cdot r$???

I thought $a\cdot r \in [\frac{1}{2}, 1 + \frac{1}{2})$ since $r \in (1, 1 + \frac{1}{2}]$.

But my friend says that it is $[1-\frac{1}{2^2}, 1]$.

Why and how does it happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your friend is almost right.  The correct answer is $[\frac34,1).$

Let $t=a-1$.  Then $ar=a(2-a)=(1+t)(1-t)=1-t^2$.

So if $t\in[-\frac12,0)$, then $ar\in[\frac34,1)$.

Comment: What you thought is incorrect, because you cannot take any number in the interval containing $a$ and multiply it by any number in the interval containing $r$, because $a$ and $r$ are not independent.

Comment: Thanks! I got it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your friend are wrong.

The right answer is $\left[\frac{3}{4},1\right)$ because by AM-GM
$$a(2-a)\leq\left(\frac{a+2-a}{2}\right)^2=1,$$ but the inequality does not occur:

$$2-a=a$$ is impossible.

Comment: Shouldn't $a = 1$ solve $2 - a = a$?

Comment: @SampleTime The domain is $\frac{1}{2}\leq a<1$ and $a=1$ is impossible.

Comment: Oh I see, missed that brace!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thank you very much for your excellent answer! Is the AM-GM (arithmetic mean and geometric mean inequality) common way to know the bound of a multiplied number?

Comment: @mallea It's one of common ways.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg It would be appreciated if you list other ways.

Comment: @mallea Do you know derivatives?

Comment: @mallea You could also complete the square.

Comment: Yes, of course.